# Spring SimpleJdbcCall Oracle sql/pl - Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure in a package which has it defined with three different method signatures in the same package. They vary by only a few parameters (each calls the next with a few default values).   I've over-simplified the list of columns for the sake of brevity here.  I have about 55 fields in the procedure I'm calling.

I am using the Spring class called "MapSqlParameterSource" to define the fields values I am providing:

```
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("pi_session_id", piSessionId)
            .addValue("pi_site_id", piSiteId)
            .addValue("pi_address_id", piAddressId)
            .addValue("po_status_cd", null)
            .addValue("po_status_mg", null);
```

I'm using a simple jdbc call to define the stored procedure that I want to call:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
          .withSchemaName("myschema")
          .withCatalogName("address_package")
          .withProcedureName("p_post_address");
```

And then I execute the procedure with this call:

```
Map<String, Object> resultsMap = jdbcCall.execute(params);
```

And I typically log out the results for fun while I'm dev'ing these up.

```
for (String key : resultsMap.keySet()) {
      logger.info("p_post_address - Key: " + key + " object: " + resultsMap.get(key));
}
```

And then I access the output fields like this:

```
String statusMessage = (String) resultsMap.get("po_status_mg");
BigDecimal statsCd = (BigDecimal) resultsMap.get("po_status_cd");
```

This works perfectly for Procedures that aren't overloaded!  However, when I call this particular procedure, it gives me this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures for 'P_POST_ADDRESS'

Then I attempted to get tricky, and specify exactly which parameters should be used to call the stored procedure, so that it could match the overloaded method I wanted.

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
          .withSchemaName("myschema")
          .withCatalogName("address_package")
          .withProcedureName("p_post_address");

jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("pi_session_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("pi_site_id", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("pi_address_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("po_status_cd", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("po_status_mg", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
```

This resulted in the same error.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures for 'P_POST_ADDRESS'

I eventually found out I need to add this option:

```
jdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
```

**And that works!**  But I have no idea why.

Could someone explain why you need to add the declared parameters `addDeclaredParameter` and also to call `withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess`?

Comment: thx, helped me.

because, jdbc template try to take meta-data for procedure, and can't get it for synonym of procedure. Without it, it just call the procedure